# Rails 3 - rmagick works on server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I need to use this install ImageMagick to use this.
The servers come to implement this in production?

noob question, but I wanna know how it is implemented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to have ImageMagick installed on your server as well, if that's what you mean. Exactly how you do that depends on the server.

Answer (score 1):

I just recently rolled out rmagick/ImageMagick on a development environment, commands are the same for production environments. Hope this helps.

First off, you'll need ImageMagick installed, along with its development packages as well: 

(I used Ubuntu as my development environment, commands might differ for different environments)

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick libmagickcore-dev libmagickwand-dev
```

Then install the gem:

```
gem install rmagick
```

Or, in Gemfile

```
gem 'rmagick'
```

As far as actually using it, well installing it is as far as I got.